# "ModuleLoadException: Error loading module" when implementing SPI for keycloak

Tags: java, keycloak

Here is a repo to reproduce the error:
https://github.com/hansen-simon/keycloak-mailattachment

I try to implement an EmailSenderProvider in keycloak. I followed this documentation: https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_development/topics/providers.html

After I built the jar file, I copy it in the Dockerfile into `/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/org/keycloak/email/provider/main/` directory next to the `module.xml`. The docker image builds successfully, but when I run it I get the following error:

```
12:39:35,357 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Error during startup: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from /opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/org/keycloak/email/provider/main/module.xml
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@15.0.2//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.ModuleProviderLoaderFactory.create(ModuleProviderLoaderFactory.java:45)

...

        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from /opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/org/keycloak/email/provider/main/module.xml
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:337)

...

        ... 42 more
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.xml.XmlPullParserException: Invalid/mismatched module name (expected org.keycloak.email) (position: START_TAG seen ...?>\n<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.keycloak.email">... @2:64) 
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.invalidModuleName(ModuleXmlParser.java:374)
...
```

The `module.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.keycloak.email">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="email-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" />
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.activation.api" />
        <module name="javax.mail.api" />
        <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
        <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-common" />
        <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-core" />
        <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi" />
        <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private" />
        <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-services" />
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:15.0.2

COPY mailattachment/target/*.jar /opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/org/keycloak/email/provider/main/
COPY mailattachment/module.xml /opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/org/keycloak/email/provider/main/

COPY mailattachment/startup-scripts/* /opt/jboss/startup-scripts/

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]

CMD ["-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

the script inside startup-scripts dir:

```
embed-server --server-config=standalone-ha.xml --std-out=echo

batch

/subsystem=keycloak-server/:list-add(name=providers,value="module:org.keycloak.email.provider")

/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=emailSender:add
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=emailSender/provider=default:add(enabled=true)
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=emailSender:write-attribute(name=default-provider, value=email)

run-batch

stop-embedded-server
```

I'm suprised by the error log line `Invalid/mismatched module name (expected org.keycloak.email) ... name="org.keycloak.email">`. It looks to like the correct module name is given. What is wrong with this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by not mounting the .jar file to `/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules` but to `/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments` and remove the `module.xml` file. I updated the [repo](https://github.com/hansen-simon/keycloak-mailattachment) with a working example.